# Why is pip install not working on python 3.11.1?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pynput for a project of mine, but when try to install it, python gives me an error message. Highlighting "install". I've ticked every box in the customization section when I installed python.

```
>>> pip install pynput
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pynput
        ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I only tried pip install, because I didn't know what else to try. When I saw somebody else use pip install, they didn't use capital letters, and it worked for them. I'm using python 3.11.1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Python terminal is only suitable for python code, pip have to be used on the windows terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run `pip` in Python interactive intepreter. Pip is a program and needs to be run from the shell / command line.

Comment: I'm running it on the terminal tho.

Comment: @MidAtProgramming no, you're not. You're in a Python session. Exit that (just type `exit()` and hit Enter), then run `pip install pynput` and you'll be all set.

Comment: You enter a python session by typing py in the terminal right?

Comment: @MidAtProgramming yes (well typically that's the command on windows) but these are *shell commands* not *python commands*. So when your Python interpreter, (regardless of whether you are running that through the terminal) tries to run them, you get a rather expected Syntax Error.

Comment: Sorry, but is "pip" the shell or python command? Because when I type "pip" into the terminal, it says "'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.".

Comment: @MidAtProgramming it's a shell command, one that is obviously not properly configured in your shell.

Comment: So then how do I configure it?